# Folium Choropleth Map - ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Tags: python, folium, choropleth

I am following [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/making-3-easy-maps-with-python-fb7dfb1036) tutorial to learn how to make basic maps using Folium, but I am receiving an error from what appears to be the `fill_opacity` argument when creating the Choropleth map. The choropleth method used in the tutorial is deprecated and has been replaced with the Choropleth class, and I have updated the code accordingly. I have consulted the Folium documentation, and I don't see anything different about my code versus the example code in the documentation. Below is my code, and the error follows after.

```
import pandas as pd
import folium
import json
from folium import plugins
from urllib.request import urlopen

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ritvikmath/StarbucksStoreScraping/master/starbucksInLACounty.csv')

LAjson = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ritvikmath/StarbucksStoreScraping/master/laMap.geojson'
response = urlopen(LAjson)
laArea = json.loads(response.read())

LAzipJson = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ritvikmath/StarbucksStoreScraping/master/laZips.geojson'
response2 = urlopen(LAzipJson)
laZip = json.loads(response2.read())

numStoresSeries = df.groupby('zip').count().id

numStoresByZip = pd.DataFrame()

numStoresByZip['zipcode'] = [str(i) for i in numStoresSeries.index]
numStoresByZip['numStores'] = numStoresSeries.values

laMapChoro = folium.Map(location = [34.0522, -118.2437], tiles = 'stamenterrain', zoom_start = 9)

folium.Choropleth(geo_data = 'laZip', data = 'numStoresByZip', columns = ['zipcode', 'numStores'], 
                  key_on = 'feature.properties.zipcode', fill_color = 'YlGn', 
                  fill_opacity = 1).add_to(laMapChoro)
laMapChoro


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/ll/77znv_6d7jng9_kjkpdllhbh0000gn/T/ipykernel_960/1935902863.py in <module>
      9 folium.Choropleth(geo_data = 'laZip', data = 'numStoresByZip', columns = ['zipcode', 'numStores'], 
     10                   key_on = 'feature.properties.zipcode', fill_color = 'YlGn',
---> 11                   fill_opacity = 1).add_to(laMapChoro)
     12 laMapChoro

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/PopulationDensity/lib/python3.7/site-packages/folium/features.py in __init__(self, geo_data, data, columns, key_on, bins, fill_color, nan_fill_color, fill_opacity, nan_fill_opacity, line_color, line_weight, line_opacity, name, legend_name, overlay, control, show, topojson, smooth_factor, highlight, **kwargs)
   1203             color_data = data.to_dict()
   1204         elif data:
-> 1205             color_data = dict(data)
   1206         else:
   1207             color_data = None

ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not passing in your data, but strings. This worked for me:

```py
folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=laZip,
    data=numStoresByZip,
    columns=["zipcode", "numStores"],
    key_on="feature.properties.zipcode",
    fill_color="YlGn",
    fill_opacity=1.0,
).add_to(laMapChoro)
```

Comment: Sometimes I guess you just need a fresh set of eyes. Thanks for your help!